# Null payload from post request in Web API with JWT Bearer authentication

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt, bearer-token

I'm using Asp.NET Web API with JWT Bearer authentication and the `sampleModel` parameter in `Sample` method shows null for some reason when I do not pass the bearer token. The strange thing is when I set the bearer token it works fine.
Does it have something to do with how I have set up my JWT authentication or is it something else I'm missing here?

The code I'm working with is as follows:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/accounts/OTP")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class OTPController : BaseApiController
{
    [Route("Sample")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Sample(SampleModel sampleModel)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

My BaseApiController class is:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    private readonly CurrentRequest _currentRequest;
    public BaseApiController(CurrentRequest currentRequest)
    {
        _currentRequest = currentRequest;
        if (_currentRequest.Value == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Request", "HttpRequestMessage is null");

        if (RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = RequestContext.Principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = RequestContext.Principal;
        }
    }
}
```

SampleModel class is:

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Apparently, I was reading the contents of the post body before it even got to the controller.

As I am using OWIN authentication I am creating OWIN Context per request `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);` and in this `Create` method I was reading the contents by 
`OwinRequestExtensions.GetBodyParameters(context.Request).Where(b => b.Key == "tenant")?.FirstOrDefault().Value;` when the user was not authenticated. Removed it and its working now.